# LibreOffice Writer: Inserting a figure into a two column document

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-writer, text-formatting

I edit a two column document in LibreOffice.

I need to to add a figure (frame?) with a program listing. I want it to be of the width of two columns.

I can make it either the width of a column (what is too thin) or the entire page including margins.

I want it to make page width minus margins.

Can you help me?